# How to define the dynamic argument of function

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a class of message body, it has two arguments, the message type and the payload of message.

```
class Message {
  final int messageType;
  final DynamicType payload;
}
```

The payload of message is dynamically, which also have a dynamic receive callback. If the messageType is 1 and the payload is Payload1, else if the messageType is 2 then payload is Payload2.

```
class Payload1 {
  ...
}

class Payload2 {
  ...
}

Future<void> receivePayload(int messageType, DynamicType payload) {
  ...
}
```

How to define the DynamicType of payload?

Comment: This is what you are looking for: https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#generics

Answer (score 2):

You can use either var Or dynamic.
Ex. var payload;

Or

dynamic payload;

Answer (score 1):

first, you should create dynamic, payload1, and payload2 classes. please note that your two last classes should extend the last one!

```
import 'dynamic_type.dart';

class Message {
  int messageType;
  DynamicType payload;

  Message({this.messageType, this.payload});
}

class DynamicType{

}

import 'package:test_app/dynamic_type.dart';

class Payload1 extends DynamicType{
  int x;
  String y;

  Payload1({this.x, this.y});
//etc


}


import 'package:test_app/dynamic_type.dart';

class Payload2 extends DynamicType{
  String x;
  int y;

  Payload2({this.x, this.y});
//etc

}
```

and now you can use as follow:

```
if(your_condition){
        message = Message(
          messageType: 0,
          payload: Payload1(
            x: 10,
            y: "test"
          )
        );
      } else {
        message = Message(
            messageType: 0,
            payload: Payload2(
                x: "another class",
                y: 10
            )
        );
      }
```

Actually, you can use "dynamic" or "var" types, but they may be confusing if your classes vary too much!